# Google analytics incorrectly labels all goal conversions as coming from repeat visitors

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up an event based goal on 2 sites which fires when the user converts. On one site everything is fine - 80% conversions come from new visitors, 20% from repeat visitors, but for some reason it says that 100% of conversions came from repeat visitors, which I'm sure is not correct. What can cause this?

Comment: Does you conversion process send users to a third party that they have to come back from?   For example a checkout that uses Paypal?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, yes, it does! Though it's the same on both sites and on the first one this doesn't break reporting

Comment: Do you currently use the [referral exclusion list](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en)?   Having that set up for one site and not the other could explain the differences.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, that doesn't seem to be the case - I've checked both lists and each one only has its own domain. I haven't known of or used this feature before

Comment: are you using the same analytics code for both sites?

Comment: @JoshSalganik the only difference is that on the first one the code is UA-90246172-1, and on the second UA-90246172-2